# RDP can not connect

Tags: amazon-web-services

I accidentally disabled the public checkbox on port 3389 in the Windows Firewall system on my RDP. I can't connect my RDP, but I've added public access in AWS security group for the port.

Can you please let me know on how to enable the port on windows firewall and connect to my RDP?

Comment: Do you have any way to remote execute scripts on this Windows instance? For example PowerShell remoting or AWS Systems Manager Run Command. Some other potential options: https://www.interfacett.com/blogs/how-to-remotely-enable-and-disable-rdp-remote-desktop/

Comment: I can see Run a Command in Systems Manager and asking the first option of Command Name. I don't know which one I choose.

Once I set public 3389 port in firewall inbound rule, RDP will work.
Can you please let me know how to enable the port in my window server 2012?

Comment: You're going to have to do some investigation here. First of all, you'll have to work out if you can execute any command (e.g. dir c:\\) remotely on the Windows instance. Once you've determined that you can, if indeed you can, then you'll have to work out what command line to use to re-configure the Windows firewall (probably `netsh advfirewall ...`). Another option, of course, is to simply terminate this instance and start a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem and now I can connect my RDP.

Step to reproduces
1. Logged on AWS and goto SSM 
2. Run a Command
3. Disable firewall (Because I have disabled my public port in Firewall)
4. Connect my RDP (It's working without a firewall - Firewall status is False)
5. Logged on my RDP and enabled the public port after that will enable the firewall again.